# Get COM port values for a specific COM Port

Tags: c#

I need to pull the COM port values from the device manager for a port.  I have found lots to find the COM name, friendly name but not actual settings.  I am talking about, baud rate, data bits, parity, stop bits, flow control.  Figured something like this;

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
{
    var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());
}
```

But I am unable to find the right query for the actual data.

thanks

Comment: The device manager doesn't has these settings as they depend on the connected COM peripheral and there is no inherent negotiation protocol between the PC and COM port peripherals. Whenever you need to communicate with a COM peripheral you must set these manually, depending what is set up at the peripherals side.

Comment: @ckuri, there are baud rate settings that are defaulted on the port.  This is a holdover from DOS and can be controlled on the command line with the `mode` command.  I'm not sure how to access them programmatically, but I would guess `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` or `SetupDiOpenDevRegKey` has something to do with it.

Comment: Ah!  Found it.  [Change properties in device manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284404/change-properties-in-device-manager).  I don't see any API's to access this information.